# Is there any API that allows to install an apk in Android?

Tags: android, adb

I want to build an app able to install apps in any Android Device from my PC, I know about adb terminal application..and I could build some kind of an interface for it, but I have been trying to find any api release that allows me to do the same thing without calling to adb.exe. I dont care if is in java or any other language...anyone knows?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to do this? Is there something you want to be able to do that adb can't?

Comment: I'm trying to install from an x86 PC into a usb connected android device. But i was just trying to avoid the need of type commands in the system shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that an api exists. ADB is a client-server program that includes three components: a client, a server and a daemon, so (I think) it's not too easy to create an api. You must take into account that the ADB is the best option, and maybe you can develop a frontend (Eg: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=970348 )

But if you are just trying to install xpi:

- WHy don't you upload your app to Google Play or alternatives?
- Also you can copy the app to your phone and install it via Install File Manager or  (you need to install it first)
- Try something similar to http://www.apkinstall.com/

Comment: about your questions: My purpose is to build some kind of an offline apkstore, in my especific country conditions it's more feasible to distribute apks this way.

Answer (score 4):

You are welcome to start an activity using an `ACTION_VIEW` or `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` `Intent`, pointing to the APK file.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to install an apk from your apk which is not feasible.
You can listen to other app in your app by broadcasting in other app and receiving that broadcast in your app .

Comment: no, this is not my purpose, I'm trying to install from an x86 PC into a usb connected android device.